# Manipulate[] does not work properly

Tags: manipulate

```
es[e1_, w2_, δx_, δy_, x_, y_] = e1*Exp[-((x - δx)^2 + (y - δy)^2)/w2^2];

el1[e2_, wl2_, x_, y_, t_] =  e2*Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/wl2^2]*Exp[I*SawtoothWave[t]];

sum1[e1_Real, w2_Real, δx_Real, δy_Real, e2_Real, wl2_Real, t_Real] :=  NIntegrate[
  (Abs[es[e1, w2, δx, δy, x, y]  + el1[e2, wl2, x, y, t]])^2
, {x, 0, wl2}
, {y, -(wl2^2 - x^2)^0.5, (wl2^2 - x^2)^0.5}
]

Manipulate[
    Plot[sum1[100, 0.00001, δx, 0, 100, 0.00001, t] 
      , {t, 0, 10}
    ]
  , {δx, 0, 1}
]
```

When I execute this code, the result of `Manipulate[]` is first shown as `"Aborted"`. Sometime later a plot does show up, but it does not respond to changes in the parameter value, and the program runs really slow.
What is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: It just takes a lot of time to create such plot and `DynamicEvaluationTimeout` is by default `5` sec. Take a look at `ControlActive` and use it for `MaxRecursion` and `PlotPoints` of `Plot`. Additionally take a look at `SynchronousUpdating -> False`.